# RXJS Observable missing definitions

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, rxjs, angular-cli

I started a new AngularCLI project in Visual Studio Code.  I'm using rxjs Observables, however, Observable is missing a lot of definitions compared to another AngularCLI project.  Both projects are using rxjs version 5.4.2.  My new AngularCLI project shows only 3 definitions for Observable and is finding those definitions in node_module\rxjs\add\operator.  However, my other AngularCLI project lists 127 definitions for Observable but finds them in node_module\rxjs\add\observable as well as node_module\rxjs\add\operator.

Here's an image of project with **3 definitions** sourced from node_module\rxjs\add\operator:

[image]

Here's an image of project with **127 definitions** sourced from node_module\rxjs\add\observable and node_module\rxjs\add\operator:

[image]

I've verified that node_module\rxjs\add\observable and node_module\rxjs\add\operator folders are the exact same in each project.

Why is one project pulling definitions from multiple locations?  How do I get my project to find all of the definitions for an Observable?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It's very possible that in your larger project that you have imported the entire rxjs library by doing something like

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
```

When it should be

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

Without seeing all your usages of `rxjs`, this is my best guess.